# Calculate mean for the duplicate columns comparing a reference dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to calculate the mean value for a data frame by comparing it with a reference data set.

In the below example, df1 is the reference data frame where df1$ID is the column names of df2. I want to calculate the mean value df2 for every duplicate values in the corresponding  df1$Ref.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = paste("R",1:7,sep = "_"), "Ref" = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),c(2,2,1,2)))

df2 <- data.frame("G.Na" = paste("Neo",1:5,sep = "."), "R_1" = 10:14, "R_2"= 1:5,
                  "R_3"= 2:6,"R_4"= 7:11, "R_5"= 0.2:0.6,"R_6"= 9:13,"R_7" = 23:27)


result <- data.frame("G.Na" = paste("Neo",1:5,sep = "."), "R_1" = 5.5:9.5, "R_3"= 4.5:8.5,
                  "R_5"= 0.2:0.6,"R_6"= 16:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `df1$ID` is in the same order as the column names in `df2`. We can use `split.default` to split the columns based on levels in `df1$Ref` and then calculate `rowMeans` for each group using `sapply`.

```
cbind(df2[1], sapply(split.default(df2[-1], df1$Ref), rowMeans))

#  G.Na    A   B   C  D
#1 Neo.1 5.5 4.5 0.2 16
#2 Neo.2 6.5 5.5 0.2 17
#3 Neo.3 7.5 6.5 0.2 18
#4 Neo.4 8.5 7.5 0.2 19
#5 Neo.5 9.5 8.5 0.2 20
```

If they are not in the same order we may need to `match` them first

```
cbind(df2[1], sapply(split.default(df2[-1], 
              df1$Ref[match(names(df2)[-1], df1$ID)]), rowMeans))
```

Comment: Was not aware of split.default function. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R` with `split` itself.  Note that this will also take of any order of the column names

```
cbind(df2[1], sapply(split(df1$ID, df1$Ref),
           function(x) rowMeans(df2[as.character(x)])))
#   G.Na   A   B   C  D
#1 Neo.1 5.5 4.5 0.2 16
#2 Neo.2 6.5 5.5 0.2 17
#3 Neo.3 7.5 6.5 0.2 18
#4 Neo.4 8.5 7.5 0.2 19
#5 Neo.5 9.5 8.5 0.2 20
```